# Immutable redux object update inside an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have the following array of object structure and based on an API response, I would like to insert a new key-value pair to all nested objects. am I mutating the nested objects with my solution down below? if yes, what would be a better implementation of this to comply with the Immutable update pattern?

**Reducer structure**

```
[{
    recordID: '4B6987A1-4179-426A-B38A-8B122995D0F8:ABPerson',
    givenName: 'A',
    middleName: '',
    familyName: '',
    phoneNumbers: [{ label: 'mobile', number: '12345679' }],
}]
```

**Incoming data structure**

```
[{
        recordID: '4B6987A1-4179-426A-B38A-8B122995D0F8:ABPerson',
        givenName: 'A',
        middleName: '',
        familyName: '',
        isUser: true,    // the new key-value pair
        phoneNumbers: [{ label: 'mobile', number: '12345679' }],
}]
```

**The way I am currently updating the store**

```
case GET_NON_USERS_SUCCESS: {
      const newArr = state.inMemoryContact.map((record, index) => {
        return {
          ...record,
          ...action.payload.getNonUsers[index]
        };
      });

      return {
        ...state,
        inMemoryContact: newArr
      };
    }
```

**Here is the action**

```
const getNonUsersSuccess = data => ({
  type: GET_NON_USERS_SUCCESS,
  payload: data
});
```

Comment: can you show your `action`?

Comment: I have edited the question to include the action.

Comment: @amo Looks good to me. Why do you think that you're not following the immutable pattern?